# Visual Studio/TFS error on Check In: The parameter is incorrect

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to do a TFS (2010) Check-In from Visual Studio (2010). I'm getting the following very descriptive & informative error message:

```
Visual Studio

The parameter is incorrect
```

[image: The parameter is incorrect]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 32):

Restarted Visual Studio and it fixed itself.

Comment: for me that was "get the latest version" on the sln file

Answer (score 0):

```
 Go to Source Control Explorer ,expand the project >> Perform undo pending changes from there
```

Make sure your package.config doesnt have any conflicts